# Firebase retrieve autoId value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve images values. Node look like this so, I would like to retrieve url1, url2, url3.

```
 "Post": {
    "uid": {
      "Text": "some text",
      "images": {
         autoID1: url1,
         autoID2: url2,
         autoID3: url3
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that key is auto generated. So, I usually cast like this.

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Anyobject] 
let text = dictionary["text"] as? String
```

but in this case I don't know how to cast autoID key and get value.
I tried code below but error said

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10af491c8) to
>   'NSString' (0x10a0bad68).

```
 func fetchImages() {
    ref.child("Post").child(uid!).child("images").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let downloadUrl = snapshot.value as! String
            let stoRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: downloadUrl)

            stoRef.getData(maxSize: 1*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.imagesArray.append(pic!)
            })

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

also if there are three url, should I use like `for snap in snapshot.children`  to loop through? How should I loop through those url and put into imagesArray?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. The thing to remember is that when you get the

```
.child("images")
```

it's actually a node that contains children

```
"images": {
   autoID1: url1,
   autoID2: url2,
   autoID3: url3
```

and isn't a string but another key: value pair where the key is "images" and the value is the child nodes.

To get the children, iterate over the child nodes in the snapshot, casting each one as a snapshot (another key: value pair) with the key being autoID1 etc and the value is the url (a String)

```
let imagesRef = self.ref.child("Post").child("uid_0").child("images")
imagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        //let key = snap.key  //autoID1, autoID2 etc
        let downloadUrl = snap.value as! String
        let stoRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: downloadUrl)
        //get your pic
    }
})
```

if ref is a class var, as it appears in your question, it should be referenced as

```
self.ref
```

Also, if you want to leave an observer on the node so you can be notified of changes, use .observe. In my case I just wanted to read it one time so I used observeSingleEvent as I only wanted to read it once.

Comment: Thank you so much Jay it perfectly worked!! Thank you for your detailed explanations as well:)